# Is it possible to render multiple instances of the same object in libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx

I currently have a class called Human, composed of several methods such as render() and update(). This is what it looks like:

```
public class Human implements Entity {

    private Texture img;
    private Vector2 pos;
    private float time;

    public Human() {
        img = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("humanFF.png"));

        // coordinates of the human initial position
        pos = new Vector2(18,420);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(SpriteBatch batch) {
        batch.draw(img, pos.x, pos.y);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(float delta) {
    }     
}
```

In my gameScreen class, I created an instance of this class as a new object, `human = new Human();` To render it, I had to use `.update(delta)` and afterward use `.render(batch)` thus creating a 'human' on my gameScreen. This is how I did it.

```
public class GameScreen extends ScreenAdapter implements InputProcessor {

    public static final int WIDTH =  1000;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 800;

    public boolean run = true;

    public float offsetX, offsetY = 0;
    private final SpriteBatch batch;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private IsometricRenderer renderer;
    private Human human;


    public GameScreen(SpriteBatch batch) {
        this.batch = batch;
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        camera.zoom = 0.3f;
        camera.position.set(WIDTH / 2f - 500, HEIGHT / 2f, 10);
        renderer = new IsometricRenderer();

        // instantiate a new human object
        human = new Human();

        // Tried to create more humans but was not sure how to render them.
        List<Human> humanList = new ArrayList<Human>();
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            humanList.add(new Human());
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

        handleInput();

        human.update(delta);

        camera.update();

        batch.begin();

        renderer.draw(batch);
        human.render(batch);


        batch.end();
    }
}
```

My problem now is how do I render multiple humans on my screen without having to re-instantiate a  `Human()` object? I tried adding new humans using a for loop but have no idea how to render them as seen in my code. I do not want to create repetitive code where I create `human1 = new Human()`, `human2 = new Human()` etc and render them using the render function one by one.

Comment: Since you're creating a list of `Human`s, just use that list in the render method. Instead of saying human.update(delta), do the same for each element in your list. The same goes for the render method.

Comment: I have tried creating a ```private int humanList``` and then doing ```humanList.update(delta)``` as well as for the render however, it throws me an error stating that it cannot invoke because this.humanList is null.

Comment: If you can, pls elaborate on your suggestion!

Comment: please take a look at the answer by Tobias. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach you described in your question is good. You can create a list of `Human` objects and iterate over them to render multiple instances. You just need to use a global list instead of a list that only exists within the `show()` method:

```
public class GameScreen extends ScreenAdapter implements InputProcessor {

    public static final int WIDTH =  1000;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 800;

    public boolean run = true;

    public float offsetX, offsetY = 0;
    private final SpriteBatch batch;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private IsometricRenderer renderer;
    // private Human human;
    private List<Human> humanList = new ArrayList<Human>();

    public GameScreen(SpriteBatch batch) {
        this.batch = batch;
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        camera.zoom = 0.3f;
        camera.position.set(WIDTH / 2f - 500, HEIGHT / 2f, 10);
        renderer = new IsometricRenderer();

        // instantiate a new human object
        // human = new Human();

        // instantiate a list of humans
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            humanList.add(new Human());
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

        handleInput();

        for (Human human : humanList) {
            human.update(delta);
        }
        
        camera.update();

        batch.begin();
        
        renderer.draw(batch);
        
        // you can use a for-each loop like the one above or an index-based loop. It doesn't realy matter. Just use the one you prefer
        for (int i = 0; i < humanList.size(); i++) {
            humanList.get(i).render(batch);
        }

        batch.end();
    }
}
```

Now you just need to change the position of the humans in the list. Otherwise they will probably all be drawn at the same position, so it seems to be only one human.

Comment: I have accepted this answer. Thank you for the clear cut explanation @Tobias, I knew I was close to a solution but lacked prior knowledge!